# Cómo puedo detener un temporizador con OnBackPressed()?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un temporizador, si me salgo de mi app con `OnBackPressed()` marca error.

Mi código:

```
 public void startTimer(final long finish, long tick) {

        t = new CountDownTimer(finish, tick) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long remainedSecs = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                textViewTiempo.setText("" + (remainedSecs / 60) + ":" + (remainedSecs % 60));// manage it accordign to you
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTiempo.setText("00:00:00");
                alerta();
               stopReapiting();
                cancel();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se genera porque el temporizador no es una variable global y cuando sales de la app esta sigue ejecutandose, te dejo un ejemplo de como deberías de utilizarlo en el onBackPressed()

```
public CountDownTimer miCronometro;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    builder.setMessage("¿Quieres salir de la aplicación?")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_balon)
            .setTitle("Abandonar partida")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    miCronometro.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Gracias me ha ayudado, se arregló llamando al método cancel(). dentro del método onBackPressed()